# Can I have a dynamic webpage in a static website?

Tags: java, apache

I have a website which is static (html), served via Apache. Due to some reasons I have to have a dynamic webpage where I could access different users different elements like facebook pages or youtube channels. It is built using java and mysql.

**Question**: Can I have a dynamic webpage in a static website? Or do I have to totally convert my website to dynamic? (is that possible?)

Comment: Use an iframe? Not entirely sure what else to suggest based on the limited information.

Comment: @AndyHolmes What more information do you need?

Comment: What exactly is the "dynamic webpage" you mention? Depending on the scale of the site I would probably just move it all into PHP or similar and go from there. But every scenario is different and your question doesn't fully explain *why*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Apache webserver can be configured to act as a proxy that passes a request to another server like a Tomcat servlet container that actually serves the request. This is what I propose for your dynamic page.

Comment: Honestly that was what I thinking about to do but wasn't sure, need some information

Comment: Sorry, I don't know more.